# Adding multiple vacancies to google search

Tags: php, schema.org, json-ld

I have json-ld script which shows job posts google jobs section.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context" : "https://schema.org/",
      "@type" : "JobPosting",
      "title" : "<?php echo($title); ?>",
      "description" :"<?php echo($description); ?>",
      "hiringOrganization" : {
        "@type" : "Organization",
        "name" : "<?php echo($name); ?>",
        "logo" : "example.com/images/<?php echo($id);?>.jpg"
      },
      "jobLocation": {
      "@type": "Place",
        "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
          "streetAddress": "MW",
          "addressLocality": "Moscow",
          "addressRegion": "Russia",
          "addressCountry": "RU",
          "postalCode": ""
        }
      },
      "baseSalary": {
        "@type": "MonetaryAmount",
        "currency": "RUB",
        "value": {
          "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
          "value": "1500",
          "unitText": "HOUR"
        }
      },
      "datePosted" : "2021-06-21",
      "validThrough" : "2021-08-18T00:00",
      "employmentType": "FULL_TIME"
    }
    </script>
```

for the 1st post it worked, I can find the vacancy on Google Jobs section. However when I add more job posts it is not showing, I tested them [here](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results?hl=ru) says it is ok.

robots.txt content : Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap.xml
sitemap.xml content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>https://example.com</loc>
    <lastmod>2021-06-21</lastmod>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

And job posts url is https://example.com/posts/71.php   72 and so on.
Anyone who can help with this?

Comment: Not enough info provided

Answer (score 1):

Creating structured data for a job listing is contrary to **[Google's guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/job-posting#technical-guidelines)**:

> Put structured data on the most detailed leaf page possible. Don't add
> structured data to pages intended to present a list of jobs (for
> example, search result pages).

About the test validity of your structured data. Automated testing tools can skip content compliance with some Google requirements. Read more of **[General structured data guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies#quality-guidelines)**:

> These guidelines are not easily testable using an automated tool.

Answer (score 0):

In my case sitemap wasn't set correctly. Make sure your sitemap sees the posts [image]

**Discovered URLs 170**